# Correct expression for Ratio of Einstein coefficients for spontaneous and stimulated emission

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, atomic-physics, laser, photon-emission

I've come across two different ratios for Einstein's coefficients for spontaneous and stimulated emission on the internet from multiple sources, and these ratios are not equal. Please help me in understanding which one is the correct ratio?

$\frac{A}{B} = \frac{8πhν^3}{c^3}$

$\frac{A}{B} = \frac{\hbar \omega^3}{π^2c^3}$

This difference is arising because different sources are considering different expressions for Planck's radiation energy density

$\begin{equation}
u(\nu, T) = \frac{8 \pi h \nu^3}{c^3} \frac{1}{\left( \exp \left( \frac{h \nu}{kT} \right) - 1 \right)}
\end{equation}$

$u(\omega, T) = \frac{ \hbar \omega^3 }{π^2c^3} \frac{1}{\left( \exp \left( \frac{\hbar \omega}{kT} \right) - 1 \right)}$

Please explain why the two expressions for Planck's radiation energy density are differing.

[hyperphysics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/optmod/eincoef.html)

[researchgate](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Ratio-of-Einsteins-coefficients-ro-z-for-total-spontaneous-emission-and-stimulated_fig4_45909655#:%7E:text=r%200%20(%CF%89%200%20)%20%3D,A%20(i)%2021%20decreases.)

Comment: $\omega=2\pi \nu, ~~ \hbar=h/2\pi $

Comment: @Craig I have considered these values but both the expressions are not equal.

Comment: You are forgetting the $\mathrm d\nu$ and $\mathrm d\omega$ also has one last factor of $2\pi$ difference. I have always been very angry about this bad notation; we are really working with $\frac{\mathrm dI}{\mathrm d\omega}=u(\omega,T)$; the left notation makes it clear that in the transformation we have one more thing to transform, whereas the right notation makes us keep forgetting that something else is involved.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have been struggling with this for long time.